# WPF ProgressBar Control Always Overlay Webview2 in Window 7 and Blink White Dot Issue

Tags: wpf, windows-7, webview2

**Description**

Issue1 : WPF ProgressBar Control Always Overlay Webview2
Issue2 : WPF ProgressBar Control Will Blink White Dot when change Visibility in webview2

Window 10 everything is good, those Issue only appear in window 7, Is there something missing on my side?

**Version**

Runtime: 92.0.902.73

Framework: WPF

OS: Win7

**Repro Steps**

Issue 1

1. Create a Simple WPF Project
2. Add Webview to Xaml window (Panel index)
3. Add ProgressBar Control in center window and set visibility to visible
4. Run Project and even set Webview2 z-index =1 and ProgressBar = 0, After the Source loaded, ProgressBar still overlay webview.

Issue 2

1. Create a Simple WPF Project
2. Add Webview to Xaml window (Panel index)
3. Add ProgressBar Control in center window and set visibility to visible
4. Add Button to set ProgressBar visibility to hidden
5. Run Project and click Button make ProgressBar hidden, the Webview will Blink White Dot (as image shown below Screenshots Issue2)

**Screenshots**
Issue 1
[image]

Issue 2
[image]

**Code**

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Source = "https://www.google.com" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1463" Margin="37,0,-8,-31" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
    <ProgressBar 
        x:Name="objLoading"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Width="50" Height="50"
        IsIndeterminate="True"
        />
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,550,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
 private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (objLoading.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            objLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            objLoading.IsIndeterminate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            objLoading.IsIndeterminate = true;
            objLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Try using: `Display: None;` instead

Comment: Always look here before going to the trouble of writing a good WebView2 question for SO.  https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues  It has plenty of subtle bugs, esp in compatibility with aging Windows platform versions.